Emmanuel Turquin's energy compensation method for thin walled glass is losing energy. Theoretically speaking, how can that happen?
I'm using Turquin's method to compensate for energy losses in my BSDFs. I'm currently working on thin walled glass (with a microfacet distribution, this is not just pure specular thin glass).
The idea of Turquin's paper is to precompute the directional albedo of the BSDF you want to compensate. For dielectrics, the LUT is 3D, parameterized by cos_theta_o, roughness and IOR. You can then fetch a value in that LUT at runtime to divide (for dielectrics) the BSDF by.
The way I understand it, dividing the BSDF evaluation by the directional albedo of that same BSDF should always "force" the BSDF to integrate to 1.
Trying to put that more formally:

At runtime, I integrate my BSDF over incident light directions (for a given camera ray, i.e. fixed view direction $w_o$), in a uniform lighting setup (i.e. furnace test)
That integration is going to yield some value $\rho$.
Because the view direction $w_o$ is fixed here, this $\rho$ value is actually the directional albedo of the BDSF for direction $w_o$.

My precomputed LUT (following Turquin's method) allows to also fetch the directional albedo of the BSDF $\rho_{LUT}$.
Dividing each evaluation of my BSDF  by $\rho_{LUT}$ should then yield an integrated value of $\frac{\rho}{\rho_{LUT}} = 1$ since those two rhos are basically the same.
Yet in practice, this is not nearly the case and the energy loss is measurable.
Here's a screenshot of the energy loss remaining even after compensation by dividing by $\rho_{LUT}$. This is at IOR 3.0 on spheres of increasing roughness. The higher the roughness, the higher the energy loss. 300 bounces. LUT size is 256x256x256 to make sure precision isn't the issue (Emmanuel Turquin uses 32x32x32).

It is worse without compensating:

The question of this post is whether the simple fact of dividing by $\rho_{LUT}$ should suffice to totally compensate for the energy loss. If so, then I assume that the issue must be in my precomputation of the directional albedo.
